# Using GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX with Open GL ES 3.0

Tags: java, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a simple cube using triangle fans in Open GL ES 3.0. Enabling `GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX` let me define the 2 fans needed to draw the cube.

The result I get is an error (Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74d7e390 in tid 3055 (GLThread 139)) and an app crash...

To help you find where the mistake could be, I add the code I use below.

Cube definition :

```
    //             4--------7
    //            -|       -|
    //           - |      - |
    //          0--------3  |
    //          |  |     |  |
    //          |  5-----|--6
    //          | -      | -
    //          |-       |-
    //          1--------2
    // point 0
    coord[0]=-0.5f;
    coord[1]=0.5f;
    coord[2]=0.5f;
    coord[3]=1f;

    // point 1
    coord[4]=-0.5f;
    coord[5]=-0.5f;
    coord[6]=0.5f;
    coord[7]=1f;

    // point 2
    coord[8]=0.5f;
    coord[9]=-0.5f;
    coord[10]=0.5f;
    coord[11]=1f;

    // point 3
    coord[12]=0.5f;
    coord[13]=0.5f;
    coord[14]=0.5f;
    coord[15]=1f;

    // point 4
    coord[16]=-0.5f;
    coord[17]=0.5f;
    coord[18]=-0.5f;
    coord[19]=1f;

    // point 5
    coord[20]=-0.5f;
    coord[21]=-0.5f;
    coord[22]=-0.5f;
    coord[23]=1f;

    // point 6
    coord[24]=0.5f;
    coord[25]=-0.5f;
    coord[26]=-0.5f;
    coord[27]=1f;

    // point 7
    coord[28]=0.5f;
    coord[29]=0.5f;
    coord[30]=-0.5f;
    coord[31]=1f;

    drawingOrder=new short[17];

    // first triangle fan : front, top and left faces
    drawingOrder[0]=0;
    drawingOrder[1]=1;
    drawingOrder[2]=2;
    drawingOrder[3]=3;
    drawingOrder[4]=7;
    drawingOrder[5]=4;
    drawingOrder[6]=5;
    drawingOrder[7]=1;
    drawingOrder[8]=-1;

    // second triangle fan : bottom, back and right faces
    drawingOrder[9]=6;
    drawingOrder[10]=2;
    drawingOrder[11]=1;
    drawingOrder[12]=5;
    drawingOrder[13]=4;
    drawingOrder[14]=7;
    drawingOrder[15]=3;
    drawingOrder[16]=2;
```

Draw function :

```
    public void draw(float [] transformMatrix) {
        GLES30.glUseProgram(programmeOpenGL);

        verticePositionIndex = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(programmeOpenGL, "positionsSommets");

        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(verticePositionIndex);

        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(verticePositionIndex , NB_COORDINATES_PER_VERTICE, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, verticeMemorySize, verticesList);

        verticeColorIndex= GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(programmeOpenGL,"couleursSommets");

        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(verticeColorIndex);

        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(verticeColorIndex, 4, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, colorList);

        transformMatrixIndex = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(programmeOpenGL, "matriceTransformation");

        GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrixIndex , 1, false, transformMatrix, 0);

        GLES30.glEnable(GLES30.GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX);

        GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,17,GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,verticesOrderList);

        GLES30.glDisable(GLES30.GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX);

        GLES30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(verticePositionIndex );

        GLES30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(verticeColorIndex);
}
```

I can add that if I only draw a single fan (either the first or the second one), it is correctly displayed...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just encode the equivalent binary value of `0xFFFF` (unsigned 65535) as a Java `short`. For a signed short `0xFFFF` = -1. When you copy across the buffer it will "just work".

Comment: That's the idea I just had, but it's not better... I have added some code in the  to help you find where the problem really is.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Encoding -1 is definitely the fix for polygon restart, so if you are having problems it's unrelated to this ...

Comment: That's what I thought after seeing that entering -1 didn't solve the problem and that's why I added my code in the question. I can add that keeping only the first triangle fan leads to a correctly displayed face. Adding a second face causes an app crash (error : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74d7e3b0 in tid 5585 (GLThread 179))

Comment: What's the actual backtrace you get (see Android tombstone file)? What device are you using? Try using triangle strip rather than triangle fan, and see if that works any better?